# "Als gutes" vs "Mit gutem Beispiel vorangehen"

Tags: difference

Bislang bin ich auf die beiden Ausdrücke gestoßen, allerdings kann ich keinen Unterschied zwischen ihnen erkennen. Gibt es welchen oder nicht?

> Europa muss bei der Einführung nachhaltiger Formen der Energienutzung **als gutes Beispiel vorangehen**
>   sie müssen gewährleisten, dass Manager **mit gutem Beispiel vorangehen**, und eine offene transparente Kultur schaffen

Comment: Das ist derselbe Unterschied, der zwischen den folgenden Sätzen besteht: 1. *»Ich gehe **als Trump** zum Karnevalsumzug«* Dabei sehe ich selbst wie Trump aus, weil ich eine entsprechende Verkleidung trage. 2. *»Ich gehe **mit Trump** zum Karnevalsumzug«* Dabei ist es mir gelungen, Trump dazu zu überreden, mich zu begleiten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Mit gutem Beispiel vorangehen:** Man hat ein gutes Beispiel und geht mit diesem voran.

**Als gutes Beispiel vorangehen:** Man selbst ist das gute Beispiel und geht als dieses voran.

---

Wenn Manager ein gutes Beispiel für irgendetwas haben, mit dem sie vorangehen, dann **gehen** sie eben **mit gutem Beispiel voran**.

Wenn Europa selbst ein gutes Beispiel für irgendetwas ist, und Europa mit eben diesem Beispiel vorangeht, dann **geht** Europa **als gutes Beispiel voran**.